# Reading from the HTML DOM returns UTF-8 characters

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8

I have a `contenteditable` `div` where I'm reading individual characters and sending them off to a server (for more background this is similar to Google Wave where typing a character automatically sends it)

I was using a plain old html `textfield` before and everything worked fine until I "upgraded" to a contenteditable div.

My problem is that now the characters are in UTF-8 format, which is causing some weird problems on the server that I would rather not debug. It would be much easier to force everything to be ASCII on the client side.

Is there any way to do this? I tried putting in a meta tag stating the html file is `charset=ISO-8859-1`, but it doesnt seem to work. Reading from the div tag still returns UTF-8 codes. (One example is when I press space I get the pair `0xC2 0xA0` which corresponds to a "non-breaking white space"

Comment: Wow....I must be tired.  You said right in your question that you tried the META tag.  I'll see if I can find anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using ASCII for user input? You're just delaying an enormous headache.

But, to answer your question: if your application expects ASCII, you need to check user input and convert it to ASCII manually. It sounds like you need to be checking every keystroke and converting it on-the-fly before it is even rendered to the screen. `charset` doesn't apply to user input, that is dependant on system-specific settings.

But again: just use UTF-8.